# Quotation marks are too wide when using minted with BW style for Haskell highlighting

Tags: minted

I'm using minted with BW style for syntax highlighting of Haskell code.

Double quotation marks are coming out wider than all of the other characters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{haskell}
> insertionSort ["elephant","zebra","gnu","buffalo","impala"]
["buffalo","elephant","gnu","impala","zebra"]
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image: result of typesetting, showing wide quotation marks]

Also, I would prefer not to have strings in italics.

The wide quotation marks appear to be a bug. Having strings not appear in italics should be a customisation option, but I can't find anything appropriate. (I thought escapeinside would help, but it doesn't work with strings.)

Comment: As always on the site please extend your example so something others can copy and test as is. My choice of preamble and class might not be yours.

Comment: @dalief I've done that now. The effect I noticed before is diminished in this version, but you can still see it - the final ] should be directly under the u in buffalo.

Comment: try loading the `upquote` package. In my book it is not a bug, it is a consequence of the font being used. this italic font does not seem to be mono space. I never use `minted` so I have no idea why it reacts so strongly when `upquote` is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the `\textit` command at the start of `minted` environments. This requires `\AtBeginEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package. Note that comments are now also no longer in italics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\let\textit\relax}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textit{italics}
\begin{minted}{haskell}
> insertionSort ["elephant","zebra","gnu","buffalo","impala"]
["buffalo","elephant","gnu","impala","zebra"]
\end{minted}
\textit{more italics}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Marijn! If I also need italics for comments - and I do - then I can force italics manually for those using escapeinside and \itshape.